# Java Apache POI - Workbook needs to be repaired after editing and saving

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

A large majority of my Java program deals with Excel and Apache POI. However, one method seems to corrupt the file, forcing the user to repair it before opening. The Excel message when attempting to open is: "We found a problem with some content in [workbook]. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

In fact, I edit this exact Workbook in another method, and there are no issues. From what I can see, I did nothing that I haven't done before in this seemingly faulty code.

```
public static void refreshExcel() {
try {
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
    sheet = workbook.getSheet("DISTRIBUTION");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    MasterLog.appendError(ex);
}//try-catch                                                                                                               
sheet.disableLocking();

//you can ignore the next 3 lines, they essentially find the rows that need to be updated
ArrayList<String> list = Log.modelLackingSCs();
for (String sc : list) {
    int desiredIndex = findFirstIndex(sc);

    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(desiredIndex);
    try {
        while (row.getCell(10).getNumericCellValue() == Integer.parseInt(sc)) {
            row.createCell(8).setCellValue(OrderLog.findShipDate(OrderLog.getWB(sc)));
            row = sheet.getRow(++desiredIndex);
        }//while                                                                                                           
    } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
        MasterLog.appendEntry("ise");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MasterLog.appendError(ex);
    }//try-catch                                                                                                           
}//for                                                                                                                     
sheet.enableLocking();

try {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    workbook.write(bos);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    MasterLog.appendError(ex);
}//try-catch                                                                                                               
}//refreshExcel()
```

Comment: This code part recreates some cells in column `I` (`row.createCell(8)`) and puts values in. When this leads to a corrupt Excel workbook, then those cells must have had special meanings before changed. So you should check what exactly is contained in sheet "DISTRIBUTION" in column `I`. And you should tell us what happens if you click on `[Yes]`. What part tries Excel repairing or does removing then? `Apache poi` pays attention to the special cell meanings dependent on the version used. So the apache poi version you are using also is of interest.